# actionscript3: removeChild and addChild

Tags: actionscript-3

I add a child to stage, and i need my code trace if this child present in the stage and remove this child from this position to add it in another position in the stage

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I THINK you're asking how to move a child from one place in the display list to another. If so, you do not need to remove the child first; When you addChild to the new 'location' the child will be removed from the old location (a child can only exist in one place on the display list). That's assuming you don't need the child to disappear for some period of time before reappearing in the new location.
Alternatively you can check if a display object contains another with this.contains(referenceToChild);

Answer (score 0):

A child is on the stage if its `parent` property is not `null`:

```
trace( child.parent !== null ); // True if the child is on the stage.
```

For positioning you just need to adjust `x` and `y`.

Comment: function getList(): void{
var pattern_pID:RegExp;
current_pID = [];
pattern_pID = new RegExp(Name.text);
for (var n:int = 0; n<all_pID.length; n++)
{
if ((pattern_pID.test(all_pID[n].Name) || Name.text=="") )
{
current_pID.push(all_pID[n]);
var newString:String = ("id_"+all_pID[n].id);

 var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
 mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFFCC00);
 mySprite.graphics.drawCircle(4, 4, 4);
 mySprite.x=this[newString].x;
 mySprite.y=this[newString].y;   
    addChild(mySprite);
  
}
}
}

Comment: thanks for your replay but i don't how i can use your suggestion in my code. in previous comment i add my code. when i choose from list i add child with specific position and i need to remove it when i choose another item from list and add the child in new position